# Android project library management pattern?

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I have very general question about managing android library project and I feel it might have pretty simple solution. The library might be used as a base program for other projects, like framework but It could be better described as a group of functionalities that are the same - just to save time.

Lets say we have project where we decide to distinguish base part which is exported as `library`. 
Those library contains `activities, network utilities, some preferences and database` schema(!). 
Is there any pattern how to do this, is it a good idea to do this with **database too?**

I mean actually I've got the library but almost every method that is dependent from other one has to be overridden what causes to override almost everything.

Maybe the system should be designed with **specific cohesion strategy?**

Thanks

Comment: "...almost every method that is dependent from other one has to be overridden what causes to override almost everything." Why it has to be overridden?

Comment: Currently if you have the Functionality in one Class that call Methods used by other Objects, when you need to change that Method, all other Functionalities get changed. Here I ask more about Architecture, Design for bigger Systems.. some Tips to follow when developing Android Project where you have Networking, Databases, Designs and Logics what makes really big Systems in fact. And how to Design it with DRY rule.